# how to create Excel using apache poi with UTF-8 format

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Need help can you please tell me how to create Excel using Apache poi with UTF-8 format. I'm using XSSF Workbook class.

thanks in advance

Comment: Apache POI already takes care of all the encoding stuff for you. Why do you think something special is needed?

Comment: Show your code with what you tried.

Comment: @Gagravarr:Some systems are not recognizing Excel written from Apachae poi. After manully opening the file and saving(CTRL + s; without change in data ) the size is increasing. like from 7Kb to 14KB. Then we noticed marking it UTF-8 format the other system is recognizing. So we don't know what is getting added after ctrl +s and format was not UTF in Excel properties. So after making format UTF-8 our issue will get resolved which is manually. now we need to do it in programatically

Comment: @Suresh Koya :  XSSFWorkbook workbookExport = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbookExport.createSheet(resourceName);
XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(cellCounter);
newCell.setCellValue(value);
newCell.setCellStyle(dataStyle);
FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File(exportedFileNamePath));
workbookExport.write(fos);  
fos.close();

Comment: Did you try looking up this [thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/636702/java-io/java/POI-Log-file-xlsx-writing)

Comment: @SureshKoya  : I failed to understand in the link provided by you how just by using get encoding will solve the problem.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.11</version>
  </dependency>